# Converting a 2D figure into a cylinder in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

At the moment I have a figure that looks like this,[image]

Generated by the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np

data = np.random.rand(20,5)
rows,cols = data.shape

plt.imshow(data, interpolation='nearest', extent=[0.5, 0.5+cols, 0.5,   0.5+cols], cmap='bwr')
plt.show()
```

However I would like to 'fold' this up into a 3D cylinder, joining the left and right edges (as one would do with a sheet of paper). In other words the left edge and the right edges are actually the same edge and so I would like to join them together to form a cylinder.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: you want a 3D-figure?

Comment: Yes, a 3D cylinder is what I am after

Comment: Do you have a system that can display 3D images?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams what do you mean by this?

Comment: Matplotlib can plot 3D images I think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Poly3DCollection` is the method of choice for arbitrary 3D polygons in `mplot3d`.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

nphi,nz=12,20
r=1 # radius of cylinder
phi = np.linspace(0,360, nphi)/180.0*np.pi
z= np.linspace(0,1.0,nz)
print z

facecolors=['r','g','b','y']
cols=[]
verts2 = []
for i  in range(len(phi)-1):
    cp0= r*np.cos(phi[i])
    cp1= r*np.cos(phi[i+1])
    sp0= r*np.sin(phi[i])
    sp1= r*np.sin(phi[i+1])

    for j in range(len(z)-1):
        z0=z[j]
        z1=z[j+1]
        verts=[]
        verts.append((cp0, sp0, z0))
        verts.append((cp1, sp1, z0))
        verts.append((cp1, sp1, z1))
        verts.append((cp0, sp0, z1))
        verts2.append(verts)
        value=np.random.rand()
        print value
        col=plt.cm.bwr(value)
        print col
        cols.append(col)

poly3= Poly3DCollection(verts2, facecolor=cols  )  

poly3.set_alpha(0.8)
ax.add_collection3d(poly3)
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_xlim3d(-1, 1)
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_ylim3d(-1, 1)
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.set_zlim3d(0, 1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Could you add some comments explaining this? Thanks

Comment: Also this doesn't use the color map

Comment: I added the colormap. In my two for loops I'm manually creating the (x,y,z) vertices ( four of them, called `verts`) for each rectangle.  Each rectangle has a lower left `(i,j)`, lower right `(i+1,j)`, upper right `(i+1,j+1)` and upper left ` (i,j+1)` vertex. The x coordinate goes with the  cosine of the angle phi, the y-coordinate with the sine of the same angle. The z- coordinate just goes from 0 to 1 in 12 steps (nz=12).  `verts2` is a list that contains the vertices of all rectangles.

Comment: I was hoping for an upvote from @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, which would make my day.

Comment: Good work Roadrunner, here is an upvote... It is rather quite "nekulturny" not to upvote and accept great answers.

Comment: Sorry, @ReblochonMasque, my remark  at IgnacioVazquez-Abrams was facetious. He wasn't the original poster, he just made a remark. I was unfairly fishing for approval :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`plot_surface`](http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/surface3d_demo.html):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as axes3d

np.random.seed(2016)
data = np.random.rand(12, 20)
h, w = data.shape
theta, z = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, w), np.linspace(0, 1, h)
THETA, Z = np.meshgrid(theta, z)    
X = np.cos(THETA)
Y = np.sin(THETA)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, projection='3d')
cmap = plt.get_cmap('bwr')
plot = ax.plot_surface(
    X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, facecolors=cmap(data),
    linewidth=0, antialiased=False, alpha=0.75)

plt.show()
```

yields

[image]