# Spherical coordinates plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, sympy, matplotlib-3d

> R(teta, phi) = cos(phi^2), teta[0, 2*pi], phi[0,pi]

How to draw a graph of this function (R(teta, phi)) in spherical coordinates with the help of matplotlib?
The documentation I have not found Spherical coordinates.

Comment: You're looking for [3D polar plots](http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/surface3d_radial_demo.html), which are bundled with `mplot3d`, part of `matplotlib`.

Comment: No, this is not a function z=f(x,y), you need to generate a 2D surface in 3D. Look here: http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/trisurf3d_demo2.html or at `3DPolygonCollection` to roll your own, e.g. like this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36669358/converting-a-2d-figure-into-a-cylinder-in-python/36669840#36669840

Comment: I stand corrected, @unutbu's answer demonstrates a  way :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The code below is very much like the [3D polar plot](http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/surface3d_radial_demo.html) from the Matplotlib gallery. The only difference is that you use `np.meshgrid` to make 2D arrays for `PHI` and `THETA`  instead of `R` and `THETA` (or what the 3D polar plot example calls `P`).

The moral of the story is that as long as `X`, `Y`, and `Z` can be expressed as (smooth) functions of two parameters, `plot_surface` can plot it.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as axes3d

theta, phi = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 40), np.linspace(0, np.pi, 40)
THETA, PHI = np.meshgrid(theta, phi)
R = np.cos(PHI**2)
X = R * np.sin(PHI) * np.cos(THETA)
Y = R * np.sin(PHI) * np.sin(THETA)
Z = R * np.cos(PHI)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, projection='3d')
plot = ax.plot_surface(
    X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=plt.get_cmap('jet'),
    linewidth=0, antialiased=False, alpha=0.5)

plt.show()
```

yields

[image]

---

Typically `R`, the radius, should be positive, so you might want

```
R = np.abs(np.cos(PHI**2))
```

In that case,

```
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
cmap = plt.get_cmap('jet')
norm = mcolors.Normalize(vmin=Z.min(), vmax=Z.max())
plot = ax.plot_surface(
    X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, 
    facecolors=cmap(norm(Z)),
    linewidth=0, antialiased=False, alpha=0.5)
```

yields

[image]

Who knew `R = np.abs(np.cos(PHI**2))` is a little girl in a dress? :)

Comment: Very elegant. How do you set the colormap to say X, or R?

Comment: @roadrunner66: You can color the surface using the `facecolors` parameter: `cmap = plt.get_cmap('jet')`; `ax.plot_surface(..., facecolors=cmap(R))`.

Comment: Ty:) Facepalm. I was using that before.

Comment: @unutbu Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just for the record, "mcolors" should probably be replaced by "matplotlib.colors" (or you should specify "import matplotlib.colors as mcolors")

Comment: @Zephyr: Thanks for the correction. Indeed, I had forgotten the import.

Comment: It's beautiful but the math is wrong. Spherical coordinates have $x = r\sin\theta\cos\phi$, $y = r\sin\theta\sin\phi$, $z = r\cos\theta$

Answer (score 3):

If you want a lot of control you can use `Poly3Dcollection` directly and roll your own (allows you to have portions of the surface, that you don't plot.
Note that I changed the variables to the more common definition of phi in the azimuth and theta for the z-direction.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection
import numpy as np
from __future__ import division

fig = plt.figure()

ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
nphi,nth=48,12

phi = np.linspace(0,360, nphi)/180.0*np.pi
th = np.linspace(-90,90, nth)/180.0*np.pi



verts2 = []
for i  in range(len(phi)-1):
    for j in range(len(th)-1):
        r= np.cos(phi[i])**2     #  <----- your function is here
        r1= np.cos(phi[i+1])**2
        cp0= r*np.cos(phi[i])
        cp1= r1*np.cos(phi[i+1])
        sp0= r*np.sin(phi[i])
        sp1= r1*np.sin(phi[i+1])

        ct0= np.cos(th[j])
        ct1= np.cos(th[j+1])

        st0=  np.sin(th[j])
        st1=  np.sin(th[j+1])

        verts=[]
        verts.append((cp0*ct0, sp0*ct0, st0))
        verts.append((cp1*ct0, sp1*ct0, st0))
        verts.append((cp1*ct1, sp1*ct1, st1))
        verts.append((cp0*ct1, sp0*ct1, st1))
        verts2.append(verts   )

poly3= Poly3DCollection(verts2, facecolor='g')  

poly3.set_alpha(0.2)
ax.add_collection3d(poly3)
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_xlim3d(-1, 1)
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_ylim3d(-1, 1)
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.set_zlim3d(-1, 1)


plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: That's the best option for 1D arrays. Why isn't any of the axis automatically scaling according to perhaps the distance fro the origin?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.